# How Can I Extend The Kendo Angular Grid?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
<div kendo-custom-grid></div>
```

And have a custom function that runs every time the extended version of the grid is used, that way I don't have to repeat myself with the same method when loading the grid every time.

Since right now I'm doing:

```
<div kendo-grid></div>
```

It looks like there's a way to extend the grid using extend in the non angular kendo grid. http://elybob.wordpress.com/2013/09/06/kendo-grid-extension-tutorial/